# How can you convert this bash completion function to a zsh completion function?

Tags: bash, zsh

How can you convert this bash completion function to a zsh completion function?

This bash function allows you to tab-complete the names of directories above your current working directory so you can more quickly and accurately navigate up the file hierarchy.

Example:

```
$ pwd
/Users/me/Animals/Mammals/Ungulates/Goats/Ibex
$ upto Animals
$ pwd
/Users/me/Animals
```

Code:

```
function upto {
    if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        return
    fi
    local upto=$1
    cd "${PWD/\/$upto\/*//$upto}"
}

_upto()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    local d=${PWD//\//\ }
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$d" -- "$cur" ) )
}
complete -F _upto upto
```

I'd like to have a similar one in zsh, but I don't fully understand the mechanics of how this one works, much less how to modify it for zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this completion function

```
_upto() {
    local parents;
    parents=(${(s:/:)PWD});
    compadd -V 'Parent Dirs' -- "${(Oa)parents[@]}";
 }
```

Enable it with `compdef _upto upto`.

Test it by creating a deply nested folder: `f=/tmp/foo/bar/one/two/three;mkdir -p $f;cd $f`. Typing `upto <Tab>` should give

```
three  two    one    bar    foo    tmp
```

To reverse the directories (i.e. start proposals at root rather at `..`), remove the `(Oa)` flag from the `compadd` line.